# php transfer variables from page to another pages

Tags: php, session

i have 4 pages like below:

## page1

```
session_start();
<input type="text" name="log1" value="".$_SESSION["log1"]."">
```

## page2

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["log1"] = $_POST["log1"] 
<input type="text" name="log2" value="".$_SESSION["log2"]."">
```

## page3

```
session_start() 
$_SESSION["log2"] = $_POST["log2"] 
<input type="text" name="log2" value="".$_SESSION["log3"]."">
```

## page4

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["log3"] = $_POST["log3"] 
<input type="text" name="log2" value="".$_SESSION["log4"]."">
```

i transfer with **method post** in order page1 > page2 > page3 > page4 . if i return to page2, i not have $_SESSION["log2"] in value of input And displays it an empty field.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're using bad syntax for using PHP with HTML. Instead of:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["log1"] = $_POST["log1"] 
<input type="text" name="log2" value="".$_SESSION["log2"]."">
```

Use:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["log1"] = $_POST["log1"];
?>
<input type="text" name="log2" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["log2"]; ?>">
```

Also make sure to use form to post data to another page to set session variables.

Comment: Nope, still not a syntactically correct mix of HTML and PHP. PHP code in the first two lines need to be with `<?php .. ?>`

Comment: @Thrustmaster of course you're right. I've assumed that he posted here only parts of his code.